# First order RL circuit question

Tags: voltage, resistors, inductor, homework

I have this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f84qWT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At time t=0 we open the switch and IL = 0.At t<0 IL = 2.5A (What I mean by" At time t=0 we open the switch and IL = 0" is the inductor hasnt realized the current has changed this happens at t=0+)

So at t =0+ the inductor behaves like a current source IL = 2.5A and   and it will decay to 0 following this equation IL = Io*(1-e^(-t*R/L)) = 2.5*(1-e^(-4t))

At t->infinity the inductor behaves like a short circuit.

I don't understand what this equation I found online V = -L*dI/dt has to do with my exercise.

Comment: This will never happen: *At time t=0 we open the switch and IL = 0.*

Comment: As @Andyaka said, the premise of your entire question is incorrect. Start over, and analyze the circuit with the switch closed to determine its initial condition. We aren't going to do this for you, we don't hand out homework solutions.

Answer (score -1):

> it will decay to 0 following this equation IL = Io*(1-e^(-tR/L)) = 2.5(1-e^(-4t))

This is wrong expression ,it decays as $$I =I_oe^{-Rt/L}$$ .

> I don't understand what this equation I found online V = -L*dI/dt has to do with my exercise

You can get $$I =I_oe^{-Rt/L}$$ by using KVL in loop containing R and L after opening of switch with initial condition I(0) =2.5(if you assume current in anticlockwise direction.

from KVL - you'll get - $$ IR+L\frac{dI}{dt} =0 $$ and initial condition I (0)= 2.5 , solve this differential equation and you'll get your desired result .

Comment: I don't think the formula you wrote down is a decay.

Comment: @Miss Mulan, please take a look at graph of e^-t